# there is a way to use an object from another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-hooks

I try to extract only the **username** from the **"userPrincipalName"** and then concatenate it into the call of Axios as a parameter.

the **"userPrincipalName"** object stay inside **BANANA PAGE** and I want to use it again at **APPLE PAGE**.

in the **BANANA PAGE** I set it inside **localStore** and render function like that:

```
export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleModal: 3,
      azureLoginObject: {},
      loginSuccess: false,

    };
    this.azureInstance = new AzureInstance(credentials);
    this._onLoginSuccess = this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this);

    localStore.setItem('userPrincipalName', 'foo');

  }

  _onLoginSuccess() {
    this.azureInstance.getUserInfo().then(result => {
      this.setState({
        loginSuccess: true,
        azureLoginObject: result,
      });
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }


  render() {
    if (!this.state.loginSuccess) {

      return (
        <AzureLoginView
          azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
          onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
        />)
    }

    if (this.state.visibleModal === 3) {
      const { givenName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;
      const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <PlacesNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

and now I want to use it in the **APPLE PAGE** but I don't understand how to do it

this is my trying example :

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }


    getData = () => {
        const userPrincipalName = localStore.getItem('userPrincipalName');

        this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] })
        axios.get("https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/OrderApprove/OrderApp_Get_Orders_To_Approve/"+userPrincipalName.split('@')[0])
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data
                });
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ getData: this.getData });
        this.getData()
    }

    renderItems = (item, index) => {
        const { merhavid, yaamID, ezorID, shemEzor } = item;
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={{
                backgroundColor: '#ffff78'
            }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Info")}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>
                        {ezorID + "" + "      |" + "               " + merhavid + " " + yaamID + " " + shemEzor}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        keyExtractor={(_, index) => String(index)}
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => { return this.renderItems(item, index) }}

                    />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.bottomMainContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.bottomView} >
                        <Text style={styles.bottomTextStyle}>סה"כ: {this.state.data.length} רשומות</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: use export in the page to export the variables which can be used in other modules also export const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;

Comment: show me how to do it

Comment: why not use redux to share the app state?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a object on the state I assume it's a changing variable. If you need to have access to it across pages, and the other page is a **child** component of the first page, you can simply pass it as a prop to the child.

If it's a sibling you can pass it to the parent through a callback functions, which then passes it to the sibling as props.

The most convenient way of doing this is using `Redux`, which will store the variable globally, and then you can retrieve it in all pages you want to, by connecting each component to the Redux store.

Answer (score 0):

in the Banana Page

```
export const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.azureLoginObject;
```

in the Apple Page

```
import { userPrincipalName } from "./Banana";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application `protocol://host:port` is same across your pages, Then `localStorage` will be handy for this.

Where ever you are setting state in banana page

```
_onLoginSuccess() {
    this.azureInstance.getUserInfo().then(result => {
      this.setState({
        loginSuccess: true,
        azureLoginObject: result,
      });
      const { userPrincipalName } = result;
      localStore.setItem('userPrincipalName', userPrincipalName);
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

Then in all other pages, you can access

```
const userPrincipalName = localStore.getItem('userPrincipalName');
```

Comment: WHAT IS MEAN OF "foo" ?

Comment: its not let me setiing it the state of the banana page ..it let me setting it only inside the constructor .

Comment: @benike, I just updated the answer. You can set the localStorage value in _onLoginSuccess callback. (and remove it from earlier place).  Earlier I mentioned 'foo' just sample string value. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use props and state. concept is explain by below sample code
you can try using below

Inside the App.js

```
// pass s3Value to App2 class
<App2 s3Value={this.state.s3 />
```

Inside the App2.js

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
        z1:props.s3Value
       }
}
```

can use props inside constructor and also inside render() method like below. And can use inside the method also

```
render() {
    var z1= this.props.s3Value;
    ...
}
```